# Hi I want to make a Flat Button in flutter that changes the background of the button when I touched it but its not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a Flat Button that change the background of the Flat Button when I tocuh it
but it not working.
currently Im using statefull widget because Im changing the background and stateles widget it cant do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor:Colors.blue ,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ask me anything"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
        ),
        body: Ball8(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
class Ball8 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ball8({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Ball8State createState() => _Ball8State();
}

class _Ball8State extends State<Ball8> {
  int num = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    randomNum();
                  },
                  child: Image.asset("images/ball$num.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
    );
  }
  void randomNum(){
    
      num = Random().nextInt(6)+1;
    
  }
}
```

Comment: you want the button to change into a different color every time you click on it is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't exactly sure what you were asking. Consider editing your question. You asked for how to change the background color of a button when it is pressed.
Here you go:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Color backgroundColour = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Ask Me Anything"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              backgroundColour = Colors.red;
            });
          },
          color: backgroundColour,
          child: Text(
            'Click me!',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does using setState on the randomNumber function works ?

```
setState(() {
   num = Random().nextInt(6)+1;
});
```

you want to change the number of the ball, using different image right ? i hope this can help.
https://dev.to/codingmonkey/let-s-create-dice-game-app-using-stateful-widget-in-flutter-ml2